# Gradle project: What is use of having a test and integration folders when both contain tests?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project and in that the model structure is divided as

- main
- test
- integrationTest

I am unable to understand the cause of this division. In maven projects we just have the 2 folders as in, main and test , where the test folder contains both unit and integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add another folder under `src/` folder it means that you declare another [sourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html).

The reason for creating new source set is to separate the responsibility of modules. In you example:

- main
- test
- integrationTest

Some reasons:

1. You want each module to have its own classpath (source code + resources)
2. You would like each module to have different dependencies / scope
3. You would like to have two sorts of tests:

   - unit tests (run very fast)
   - integration tests - proofs that your components collaborate as expected.

Integration tests are mostly executed on CI infrastructure because it takes time and sometimes resources to execute them.